# Is there a way I can split this list?

Tags: python, string, list, split

Here's my string:

```
"1.Movie1|Votes:2,147,833| Gross:$28.34M  2.Movie2|Votes:42,473| 
3.Movie3|Votes:23,439| Gross:$0,27M  4.Movie4|Votes:20,940"
```

The end-goal is to use the function .split("|") and have it all nicely arranged. The problem is that some of the movies don't have a "Gross:".

I want my string to look like this:

```
"1.Movie1|Votes:2,147,833| Gross:$28.34M|2.Movie2|Votes:42,473|3.Movie3| 
Votes:23,439| Gross:$0,27M|4.Movie4|Votes:20,940|"
```

I used .replace to add more "|" to format it easier. I also tried using .split("M  "), but since some movies don't have a gross, it would put 2 movies in one line.

Comment: I don't see why you want to use `split`. Your output is not anyways a splitted input.

Comment: Are you creating this string yourself, or reading it from somewhere else? 
 If you are creating it yourself, just add an empty column wherever gross is missing.  Or better yet, use an actual data structure to store your values instead of a big string.  (I recommend a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) or possibly a [pandas DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this would do it

```
string = "1.Movie1|Votes:2,147,833| Gross:$28.34M  2.Movie2|Votes:42,473| 3.Movie3|Votes:23,439| Gross:$0,27M  4.Movie4|Votes:20,940"

string = string.replace(' ','|').replace('||G','| G').replace('||','|')
```

this is considering you need an extra space between '|' and 'G' of Gross, if this extra space is not required in the output then you may remove the `replace('||G','| G')` part from the code to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to use dictionaries than lists especially in this case.But if you are so interested in parsing the data your way, then I found a workaround for your data, Maynot work for all the data but it works perfectly well in the given sample data.

```
a="1.Movie1|Votes:2,147,833| Gross:$28.34M  2.Movie2|Votes:42,473| 3.Movie3|Votes:23,439| Gross:$0,27M  4.Movie4|Votes:20,940"
c="|".join(a.split("  "))+"|"
print(c)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using split and list comprehension like below

```py
s = "1.Movie1|Votes:2,147,833| Gross:$28.34M  2.Movie2|Votes:42,473| 3.Movie3|Votes:23,439| Gross:$0,27M  4.Movie4|Votes:20,940"

"|".join(["|".join([sp2 for sp2 in sp1.split("|") if sp2!='']) 
          for sp1 in s.split(" ") if sp1!='']) + "|"
```

**Result**

```
'1.Movie1|Votes:2,147,833|Gross:$28.34M|2.Movie2|Votes:42,473|3.Movie3|Votes:23,439|Gross:$0,27M|4.Movie4|Votes:20,940|'
```